# Need help adding integers to an integer variable in C through for loop while splitting 2 digit numbers into 2 separate numbers

Tags: c, cs50

I am writing a program that validates a credit card number based on length and Luhn’s Algorithm. You can read the assignment [here](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/psets/1/credit/).

My problem here lies on the first part of the for loop where the odd numbers from the credit card number are multiplied by 2 and added to a (long integer) variable called total. (if the card number goes 02467 it would be 6 * 2 and 2 *2 but not 12 + 4 what happens is each 2 digit number splits into 2 so 1 + 2 + 4.

The problem here is that when I add the numbers to the long variable it comes out wrong. The total should be 20 or 2 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 0 + 8. Starting from the second to last number of course.

Counting starting from second to last number is that same as all even numbers if the length of number is odd and all odd numbers if length of number is even which is what I did.

Here is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_int_len(int value);

int get_long_len(long value);

int get_digit_with_index(int index, long value);

int tens_place_int(int value);

int ones_place_int(int value);

int main(void)
{
    long card_num, len;
    do
    {
        card_num = get_long("Number: ");
        len = get_long_len(card_num);
    }
    while (len < 13 || (len > 13 && len != 15 && (len != 16)));

    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {

        if (len % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                if (get_int_len(i) > 1)
                {   total -= i;
                    total += tens_place_int(get_digit_with_index(i, card_num));
                    total += ones_place_int(get_digit_with_index(i, card_num));
                }
            total += get_digit_with_index(i, card_num) * 2;
            }
            else if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                total += get_digit_with_index(i, card_num);
            }
        }
        if (len % 2 != 0)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0 || i == 2)
            {
                if (get_int_len(i) > 1)
                {   total -= i;
                    total += tens_place_int(get_digit_with_index(i, card_num));
                    total += ones_place_int(get_digit_with_index(i, card_num));
                }
                total += get_digit_with_index(i, card_num) * 2;
            }
            else
            {
                total += get_digit_with_index(i, card_num);
            }
        }
    }

}
int get_int_len(int value)
{
    int l = 1;
    while (value > 9)
    {
        l++;
        value /= 10;
    }
    return l;
}

int get_long_len(long value)
{
    int l = 1;
    while (value > 9)
    {
        l++;
        value /= 10;
    }
    return l;
}

int get_digit_with_index(int index, long value)
{
    int l = 0;
    index = get_long_len(value) - index;
    while (index > l)
    {
        l++;
        value /= 10;
    }
    return value % 10;

}

int tens_place_int(int value)
{
    if (get_int_len(value) != 2)
    {
        printf("Not valid please enter a 2 digit number.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    value/=10;
    return value;
}

int ones_place_int(int value)
{
    if (get_int_len(value) != 2)
    {
        printf("Not valid please enter a 2 digit number.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return value % 10;
}
```

Comment: Alternate implementation: https://ideone.com/OESldI

Comment: Can you explain how num/=10 on line 14 works and how it cuts off odd numbers?

Comment: `num /= 10;` is the same as `num = num / 10;`. It divides the number by 10, "removing the last digit"... so, for example,  `4002 / 10` ==> `400` (the *odd* (original position 1) digit `2` was removed). The loop does 2 of those "removals": the first for *odd* digits, the second for originally *even* digits.